# Linked Lists and Trees - text book

Tags: tree, linked-list

Does anyone know of a great book on Trees (binary, quad trees, etc...) in C++ that would start off nice and gentle, and then gets into serious code?

I need to improve my knowledge of advanced topics, like linked lists and trees...

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming is *the* seminal book on many datastructures, but is in assembly and not C++. I still recommend it, though, as its coverage of the ideas themselves is beyond compare.

Answer (score 0):

1. Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ 
   by Michael T. Goodrich, Roberto Tamassia, David M. Mount
2. C++ Plus Data Structures
   by Nell Dale
3. C++, object-oriented data structures
   by Saumyendra Sengupta, Carl Phillip Korobkin
4. Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++
   by Weiss, Weiss Mark Allen

You can buy any book of above. But I suggest the last one is good.